# Can not get the current language to appear in the widget

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have a problem with a couple of widgets on my Wordpress site. It always takes the first language (english ) instead of the correct language that the page is on at that moment.

Here is my code from one of the widgets:

```
<?php
if ( is_active_sidebar('logostrip') ) {

    $widgets    = wp_get_sidebars_widgets(true, true, 'logostrip', true);
    $logoWidget = $widgets['logostrip'];
    $langs      = count(pll_languages_list());
    $currentLang = pll_current_language();

    for ($i=0; $i < $langs; $i++) {
        if ( $logoWidget[$i] ) {
            $logoId     = $logoWidget[$i];
            $i = $langs;
        }
    }

    $title       = get_field('header', 'widget_' . $logoId);
    $title       = preg_replace(array('/\[/', '/\]/'), array('<', '>'), $title);
    $logos       = get_field('client_logos', 'widget_' . $logoId);
    $maxItems    = 6;
```

?>

Could anybody help me with this? I have already implemented this so that it would take the current language but nothing happens.

```
$currentLang = ppl_current_language();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you using the `$currentLang` variable?

Comment: seems like you are not checking if `$currentLang` matches anything.

Comment: also - `$i = $langs;` makes sure, that the first time you hit your forloop, you update the `$i` so that you won't hit it again - making sure that you only get the first instance in the loop - that shit needs be go son!

Comment: or should only happen, if you have found the correct logo, using `$currentLang`

Comment: Did you try to print_r() the first four variables? That could be helpful

Comment: @Lis comment would help you debug, understand your variables and come up with the correct logic needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to prefer using the `get_locale()` function instead.

Anyway, what do you want to achieve ?

Because with Polylang :

- widgets are localized, so each language has his own
- theme options can be localized too with the following [plugin](https://github.com/BeAPI/acf-options-for-polylang), which could help you having different values for a same option depending on the current language
- [display](https://polylang.pro/doc/the-language-switcher/) the available language flags with PLL

Comment: Thanks! I would like to change the language of the text in the widget when the page itself is changed to a different language.

Comment: @noahf Do you mean the i18n of labels or the value from the widget itself ?

Comment: I mean the value form the widget itself. @MaximeCulea

Comment: @noahf then two solutions as mentionned :

* theme options can be localized, which help you achieve different values for a same option depending on the current language

* widgets are localized, so each language has his own. This means don't try to handle yourself, getting the widget values is automatic

Answer (score -1):

Instead of **pll_current_language();** please use **get_option('WPLANG')** to get the current language. Please copy and paste the code

```
<?php
if ( is_active_sidebar('logostrip') ) {

    $widgets    = wp_get_sidebars_widgets(true, true, 'logostrip', true);
    $logoWidget = $widgets['logostrip'];
    $langs      = count(pll_languages_list());
    $currentLang = get_option('WPLANG');

    for ($i=0; $i < $langs; $i++) {
        if ( $logoWidget[$i] ) {
            $logoId     = $logoWidget[$i];
            $i = $langs;
        }
    }

    $title       = get_field('header', 'widget_' . $logoId);
    $title       = preg_replace(array('/\[/', '/\]/'), array('<', '>'), $title);
    $logos       = get_field('client_logos', 'widget_' . $logoId);
    $maxItems    = 6;
?>
```

Hope this work you.

Comment: Still not using `$currentLang` for anything.

Comment: I have seen that, not getting data is one of the reason to not use. So I explained where the code has been changed. Hope he can undertsand it, otherwise I will explain it to him.

Comment: @Stender What would you suggest using then?

Comment: @noahf, he is actually saying the the variable $currentLang has not been used on your code, so how it can be seen that the language is not fethced. Better you can print it once to check whether the actual langugae is showing or not

Comment: @Tristup is right - What i am saying is, that you need to implement `$currentLang` in your conditions for finding the correct logo. right now, you are just checking, if the first language you hit, exists in your `$logoWidget` and then exit your loop - which is where your mistake is.

Comment: @Stender Ah okay thank you, but I am kinda new with this tho. So how could I implement this the best way in my conditions to make it work good?

Comment: `if ( $logoWidget[$i] ||  $currentLang ) {` is this the correct way of doing it? @Stender

Comment: @noahf - I wouldn't think so, this would result in the first language as well.